# Why won't my Lua script work in Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I have tried again and again to get this code to work.

```
-- Sample assembly code with labels

local assemblyCode = [[

    LOAD R1, 10

    STORE R1, 20

    ADD R1, 30

    SUBTRACT R2, 40

    JUMP_IF_ZERO R1, LOOP

    HALT

LOOP:

    ADD R2, R3

    JUMP LOOP

]]

-- Mapping of assembly mnemonics to opcodes

local opcodeMappings = {

    ["NOOP"] = 0,

    ["LOAD"] = 1,

    ["STORE"] = 2,

    ["ADD"] = 3,

    ["SUBTRACT"] = 4,

    ["JUMP"] = 5,

    ["JUMP_IF_ZERO"] = 6,

    ["COMPARE"] = 7,

    ["MULTIPLY"] = 8,

    ["DIVIDE"] = 9,

    ["LOGICAL_AND"] = 10,

    ["LOGICAL_OR"] = 11,

    ["SHIFT_LEFT"] = 12,

    ["SHIFT_RIGHT"] = 13,

    ["HALT"] = 14,

    ["MOV"] = 15,

}

-- Mapping of register mnemonics to register numbers

local registerMappings = {

    ["R1"] = 0,

    ["R2"] = 1,

    ["R3"] = 2,

}

-- Process and assemble the code

function assemble(assemblyCode)

    local assembledCode = {}

    local labelTable = {}

    for line in assemblyCode:gmatch("[^\r\n]+") do

        local parts = {}

        for part in line:gmatch("%S+") do

            table.insert(parts, part)

        end

        if #parts > 0 then

            local mnemonic = parts[1]:upper()

            if mnemonic:sub(-1) == ":" then

                local label = mnemonic:sub(1, -2)

                labelTable[label] = #assembledCode + 1

            else

                local opcode = opcodeMappings[mnemonic]

                if opcode then

                    local instruction = opcode * 32

                    if opcode == 0 then

                        -- NOOP

                    elseif opcode >= 1 and opcode <= 15 then

                        if opcode == 15 then

                            -- MOV

                            local srcRegister = registerMappings[parts[2]:upper()]

                            local destRegister = registerMappings[parts[3]:upper()]

                            if not srcRegister or not destRegister then

                                error("Invalid register in MOV instruction.")

                            end

                            instruction = instruction + (srcRegister * 4) + destRegister

                        else

                            local register = registerMappings[parts[2]:upper()]

                            local operand = tonumber(parts[3])

                            if not register or not operand then

                                error("Invalid register or operand.")

                            end

                            instruction = instruction + (register * 32) + operand

                        end

                    else

                        error("Invalid opcode: " .. mnemonic)

                    end

                    table.insert(assembledCode, instruction)

                else

                    error("Unknown mnemonic: " .. mnemonic)

                end

            end

        end

    end

    -- Replace label references

    for i, instruction in ipairs(assembledCode) do

        if type(instruction) == "string" then

            local label = instruction

            local labelAddr = labelTable[label]

            if not labelAddr then

                error("Label not found: " .. label)

            end

            assembledCode[i] = labelAddr

        end

    end

    return assembledCode

end

-- Assemble the code

local assembledCode = assemble(assemblyCode)

-- Display the assembled machine code

for _, instruction in ipairs(assembledCode) do

    if type(instruction) == "number" then

        print(string.format("0x%04X", instruction))

    else

        print(instruction .. ":")

    end

end
```

I have tried to get ChatGPT to fix it, but it refuses to work. It's meant to print the translated instructions off to the console (gonna use it elsewhere) but it keeps bringing up the register error I implemented as Workspace.Script:77: Invalid register or operand. I am running it with the Example code provided, any help welcome.

Comment: `if not register or not operand then` this will always fail for `JUMP`. `JUMP` only has an operand, no register.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the only part of the code that's wrong here. In cases like this, just manually trace through the code and see where the logic doesn't make sense.

Comment: It fixed the error their, now I'm getting one at line 87 instead! Arggg

Comment: NVM I was using lua instead of Luau, i feel very stupid lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote it in Lua instead of Luau, i had to rewrite the whole thing in the end